# How do I set a custom name for a feed in elfeed?

Tags: elfeed

I use elfeed to follow some blogs and news sites. One on them is Arne Metz's "Simplify C++". This feed does not set its name so in the *elfeed-search* buffer this field is left empty. This makes it difficult to quickly scan the list of feeds to read.

I have tried to find information on how to manually set the feed name in my init.el file but failed to find an answer that works. Is it even possible?

Configuration of elfeed in my init.el looks like the following:

```
(use-package elfeed
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq elfeed-feeds '(("http://bobby.clearit.se:8080/jenkins/job/scm/rssAll" build jenkins)
               ("http://planet.emacsen.org/atom.xml" emacs)
               ("https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/emacs" emacs stack)
               ("https://www.masteringemacs.org/feed" emacs)
               ("http://endlessparentheses.com/atom.xml" emacs)
               ("https://oremacs.com/" emacs)
               ("http://pragmaticemacs.com/feed/" emacs)
               ("https://arne-mertz.de/feed/" cpp)
               ("https://isocpp.org/blog/rss/category/news" cpp)
               ("https://www.fluentcpp.com/feed/" cpp)))
  :bind
  ("C-x w" . elfeed))
```

Is it possible to manually set the feed name from within the use-package declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be an easy way to do it using just elfeed and its variables. There is a highly recommended package [elfeed-org](http://github.com/remyhonig/elfeed-org) that has this comment in its readme: "If you want to add a custom title to a feed, that is even more cumbersome..."

Elfeed-org makes setting the feed title very easy: Instead of the plain feed URL as a header title, you can use an org link, e.g. `[[https://arne-mertz.de/feed/][Simplify C++]`.

Answer (score 1):

For others looking to change the name of a feed - it seems that this is now possible by using `M-x elfeed-search-set-feed-title`, as described [here](https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed#metadata-plist).